# How to hande clicks inside RecyclerView which updates the UI?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecylcerView which displays list of items stored in SQLite.

[image]

On each row, there's up and button which increments/decrements the amount when clicked. Let's say I klik the down button on ABCD row, then amount text will be changed into "Amount: 1"

Here's my code so far:

**ItemAdapter.java**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Itemt> itemList;
    private Context ctxt;
    private MyClickListener clickListener;

    public ItemAdapter(Context ctxt, List<Item> list, MyClickListener listener){
        this.ctxt = ctxt;
        this.itemtList = list;
        this.clickListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int type) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

        return new ItemAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Item item = itemtList.get(position);
    holder.tvName.setText(item.getName());
    holder.tvPrice.setText(item.getPrice());
    holder.tvAmount.setText("Amount: "+ item.getAmount());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvNama, tvHargaJual, tvHargaBeli, tvJumlah;
        public Button btnInc, btnDec;
        MyClickListener listener;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            tvPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
            tvAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_amount);
            btnInc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_inc);
            btnDec = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_dec);

            btnInc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    clickListener.onIncrement(view, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

            btnDec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    clickListener.onDecrement(view, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface MyClickListener {
        void onIncrement(View v, int position);
        void onDecrement(View v, int position);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recView
    DBHelper db;
    List<Item> itemList;
    Item item;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        itemtList = new ArrayList<>();

        db = new DBHelper(this);
        itemList.addAll(db.getAllItems()); // load all stored items in SQLite db

        mAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList, new ProductAdapter.MyClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIncrement(View v, int position) {
                item = itemList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDecrement(View v, int position) {
            item = itemList.get(position);
            }
        });

        }
    }
```

The current issue is when the up/down button is clicked, it cannot modify the amount text. How to correct this?

Comment: add `clickLisenter` In  `onBindViewHolder` sent the position param instead of `getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: and Implements that `listener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you must change the value of `amount` in `onIncrement` and `onDecrement`  methods. something like this:

```
item = itemList.get(position);
itme.setAmount(item.getAmount()++);
----------------------------------------------
item = itemList.get(position);
itme.setAmount(item.getAmount()--);
```

and then you must notify recyclerView adapter that data is changed by this code:

```
 mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

here are all codes together:

```
mAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList, new ProductAdapter.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIncrement(View v, int position) {
            item = itemList.get(position);
            itme.setAmount(item.getAmount()++);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDecrement(View v, int position) {
            item = itemList.get(position);
            itme.setAmount(item.getAmount()--);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the `btn.setOnClickListener()` in `MyViewHolder` class,you should do it in `onBindViewHolder()`.

**Access the element like below:**

```
@Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = itemtList.get(position);
    holder.tvName.setText(item.getName());
    holder.tvPrice.setText(item.getPrice());
    holder.tvAmount.setText("Amount: "+ item.getAmount());

    holder.btnInc.setOnClickListener(
       //do ur stuff here
     )
    holder.btnInc.setOnClickListener(
       //do ur another stuff here
      )
}
```

At the same time remove the `onClickListener()` of your button in `MyViewHolder` class. Cause `MyViewHolder` is just the place for you to find all the UI element. The operation is done in `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: for better performance, it's good to light up `onBindViewHolder()` method, because this segment code runs several times by scrolling the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the amount of the item and call mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position), 
Example:

```
mAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList, new ProductAdapter.MyClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onIncrement(View v, int position) {
                    item = itemList.get(position);
                    item.setAmount(item.getAmount()++);
                    mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onDecrement(View v, int position) {
                item = itemList.get(position);
                item.setAmount(item.getAmount()--);
                mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
                }
            });
```